# Python toolkit for disk analyzer

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, diskspace, analyzer

I'm creating a Disk Analyzer in Linux. I would like to know which Python toolkit will help me with the GUI. I'm currently trying Tkinter is there something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Better" is subjective. I will gladly offer my opinion that there is no toolkit better than Tkinter for this task. This task seemingly doesn't need much eye candy or the ability to print, which are Tkinter's weak points. Tkinter is easy to use, modern, stable, and very customizable. Plus, you probably already have it. It has a canvas widget that is incredibly easy to use if you are considering drawing heat maps or charts or graphs or whatever.

Others will no doubt say "no way! wxPython is better because...", or "no way! pyqt is better because...". And frankly, we're all right. They are all fine toolkits. For what you are doing I would argue that the toolkit doesn't matter. Pick any toolkit and use it.

Comment: I'm not sure about "modern", as it currently only supports one-bit black & white window icons on linux, rather than full colour like every other toolkit has for the last decade or so... That said, I'm personally using it for all my GUI projects for the reasons above :-)

Comment: Thank you. That does give confidence to a beginner